# Why does Java Stream.map take a Function<? super P_OUT, ? extends R> mapper as input instead of Function<P_OUT, ? extends R>?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream, wildcard

Why does `map` take its input as a `Function` of type `<? super P_OUT, ? extends R>` instead of `<P_OUT, ? extends R>`?

When I do for example,

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream().map(xyz -> {}); // Here xyz is always of type Integer for this instance. 
                              // Then why does it take input as "? super Integer"?
```

Is it because of not restricting method references? Is that the only use case?

Comment: Because it grantees right parameter and also increase range of parameters when you are using lower bound  `? super P_OUT` so here you can use `P_OUT` and all superclass of `P_OUT`

Comment: A `Function` is given input (consumes) and returns a result (produces). Using wildcards allows flexibility in the API regarding the implementation of `Function` you pass to `map`. For instance, it being `Function<? super Integer, ? extends R>` lets you pass an implementation of `Function<Number, ? extends R>`.

Comment: Slaw, I get it. So, it is to avoid the restriction right? In case the '? super Integer' is not there, I could not use method reference to use a function of type <Number, ? extends R>. Hence to overcome the restriction, they have provided "? super Integer". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Pretty much. Oleksandr's answer below gives examples. The duplicate has answers that give some decent explanations about covariance, invariance, and contravariance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wildcard `<? super T>` allows you to work with a broader set of types.

Suppose you have some *generic* function:

```
Function<Number, String> func = String::valueOf;
```

Then you could do the following:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2);
Stream<String> stream = list.stream().map(func);
```

or the following:

```
List<Long> list = List.of(1L, 2L);
Stream<String> stream = list.stream().map(func);
```

And this is possible because the parameter to the [`Stream.map(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is:

```
Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper;
```

Which means that if, for example, `T` is of type `Long`<sup>1</sup>, then `<? super Long>` will allow the function to accept elements of type `Long`, and the following assignment will also become valid:

```
Function<? super Long, ? extends String> mapper = func;
```

With the `Function<T, ? extends R>` both examples above wouldn't even compile.

---

<sup>1 - We construct the `Stream<Long>` from the elements of the `List<Long>`.</sup>